# Can't access TensorFlow Adam optimizer namespace

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, convolution

I'm trying to learn about GANs and I'm working through [the example here](https://github.com/llSourcell/Generative_Adversarial_networks_LIVE/blob/master/EZGAN.ipynb).

The code below using the Adam optimizer gives me the error

> "ValueError: Variable d_w1/Adam/ does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?"

I'm using TF 1.1.0

```py
d_loss_real = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=Dx, labels=tf.fill([batch_size, 1], 0.9)))
d_loss_fake = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=Dg, labels=tf.zeros_like(Dg)))
d_loss = d_loss_real + d_loss_fake

tvars = tf.trainable_variables()

d_vars = [var for var in tvars if 'd_' in var.name]
g_vars = [var for var in tvars if 'g_' in var.name]



# Train the discriminator
# Increasing from 0.001 in GitHub version
with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope(), reuse=False) as scope:

    # Next, we specify our two optimizers. In today’s era of deep learning, Adam seems to be the
    # best SGD optimizer as it utilizes adaptive learning rates and momentum. 
    # We call Adam's minimize function and also specify the variables that we want it to update.
    d_trainer_real = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0001).minimize(d_loss_real, var_list=d_vars)
    d_trainer_fake = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0001).minimize(d_loss_fake, var_list=d_vars)
```

I think the Adam optimizer is taking the variables into its own namespace but for some reason they aren't initialized. I do call `global_variables_initializer` later in the code, as can be seen on the github page. I'm checking through the documentation, I think it may be related to me having to put some kind of `reuse_variables()` call in there, but I'm not sure.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure that this example is the best one to follow, considering that it uses two optimizers for the discriminator. It could use the already defined d_loss to use a single optimizer, potentially avoiding this problem altogether.

Comment: Also, the discriminator output activation is linear, where it should be a sigmoid (or something else with a range from 0 to 1). This explains why the discriminator classification is negative at the 0 timestep results.

Comment: @jasekp So what would you advise? Having one optimizer for discriminator still gives me the error. I would like to get this working and understand the Adam optimizer as I think thats what the issue is here. I can always check out more examples afterwards? Any idea how I can get it working? Thanks!

Comment: [This implementation](https://github.com/ckmarkoh/GAN-tensorflow) is much more concise, and gives reliable results on MNIST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ValueError is caused by creating new variables within the variable_scope.reuse==True.

Variables are created by Adam, when you call the minimize function of Adam, for saving momentums of each trainable variables in your graph.

Actually, the code "reuse=False" DOES NOT work as you expected. The reuse state cannot change back to False forever once you set it to True, and the reuse state will be inherited by its all sub scopes.

```
with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope(), reuse=False) as scope:
    assert tf.get_variable_scope().reuse == True
```

I guess you have set reuse to True somewhere before the post codes, thus the default variable_scope.reuse==True. Then you create a new variable_scope for Adam, however, new scope will inherit the reuse state of default scope. Then, Adam creates variable under state reuse==True, which raises an error.

The solution is to add a sub scope under the graph's default scope when you set variable_scope.reuse=True, then the default scope.reuse is still False, and Adam.minimize will work.