# Change reuse statement of a cope afterwards

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there a way to change the attribute `reuse` of tensorflow variable scopes after creating the variables and after exiting the scope?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer in another stack overflow question. I'll post the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440900/cant-access-tensorflow-adam-optimizer-namespace) here, since the question where it's answered has a completely other title.